# Android Studio on Mac OS X adb connection

Tags: macos, android-studio, adb

I'm using Android Studio (1.0.2) on Mac OS X (10.10.2). I can use Eclipse with adb with no problems on my system. However, Android Studio has problems connecting to adb. The first run it works. It seems that after a certain amount of time (20 - 30 secs?) adb quits unexpectedly. Then I get the message ADB not respoding in Android Studio. Manually killing and starting adb from a terminal sometimes fixes the problem but usually makes my device (Samsung Galaxy S5) invisible to adb. There is only one adb on my system (version 1.0.32) installed.

Doing an lsof -i :5037 shows a list of 9 connections from Android Studio, all from localhost, all CLOSE_WAIT but one which is ESTABLISHED. In a working situation there are also four of them from adb, one of them LISTENING on port 5037.

I have my firewall turned off. Exiting Android Studio crashes adb one more time. Restarting it sometimes allows me to continue working, sometimes it changes nothing.

Unplugging and plugging back in my device fixes the device visibility.

Please advice what to try next because this setup is pretty unusable at the moment.

Comment: Switching from my Samsung Galaxy S5 to an HTC seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Also, running the emulator (idle) and debug on a real device also seems to fix the problem.